# JavaFX how to restart a sound file after playing to the end?

Tags: audio, javafx, media-player

I have problem with my soundplayer. I can play or stop a soundfile but I am not able to restart a soundfile after it has reached the end. whenever the end of the soundfile is reached it seems to be the status unknown or halted, but I can not react on the status.
Thanks for your help

```
public class Main extends Application {

    private StackPane root;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        //Creating button and adding an ID for CSS
        Button btnPlay = new Button("Press to play or stop");

        Media media = new Media(this.getClass().getResource("aquarium.wav").toString());
        MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(media);

        btnPlay.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            //handling status sound is playing or not playing
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

                Status status = player.getStatus();

                if (status == Status.UNKNOWN || status == Status.HALTED) {

                    System.out.println("Status unknown");

                    //what to do??????
                }



                if (status == Status.PAUSED
                        || status == Status.READY
                        || status == Status.STOPPED) {

                    player.play();
                }
                if (status == Status.PLAYING) {

                    player.stop();

                }
            }
        });

        root = new StackPane();

        root.getChildren()
                .addAll(btnPlay);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 450);

            //binding Scene to StyleStop.css
        scene.getStylesheets()
                .add(Main.class
                        .getResource("styleStop.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setTitle(
                "Mediaplayer - My SoundMachine");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);

        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: [`HALTED`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/media/MediaPlayer.Status.html#HALTED) indicates an error has occurred. You cannot transition out of that state into any other. [`UNKNOWN`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/media/MediaPlayer.Status.html#UNKNOWN) is the state before `READY`: you should probably disable the button until it reaches the `READY` state.

Comment: But how can it reach the READY state after having reached the end??

Comment: According to the docs linked above, it can't reach either `READY` or `UNKNOWN` after it starts playing. Can you add a listener to the status which displays the status transitions?